# Find the joint distribution of $(X, Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a Bernoulli random variable with a probability of success $p$ and let $Y = 1 - X$.

Find the cumulative joint distribution of $(X, Y)$

I have tried to show the joint distribution is the product of the marginal distributions, but apparently, I can not use it since both random variables are not independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going back to the definition of (discrete) [joint probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Discrete_case), you want to find the quantity:
$$
P(X=x,Y=y)
$$
Note that the event $(X=x,Y=y)$ means $(X=x\textrm{ and }Y=y)$. This event zero probability when $x+y\ne 1$ because $Y=1-X$. When $x+y=1$,
you have
$$
P(X=x,Y=y)=P(X=x,Y=1-x)=P(X=x),\quad x\in\{0,1\}
$$

Now you should know how to go on.

---

Notes.

In the calculation above, $P(X=x,Y=1-x)=P(X=x)$ because $(X=x,Y=1-x)$ and $(X=x)$ are the same event since $Y=1-X$.

Answer (score 1):

the requested joint distribution can be represented by the following table

|  | Y=0 | Y=1 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **X=0** |  | 1-p | 1-p |
| **X=1** | p |  | p |
| **Total** | **p** | **1-p** | **1** |